# Can you (MySQL) Order by values that are optional and in different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, pdo

So I am having a fairly basic PHP-based Website that uses MySQL for some of its data.

I currently need to sort a row of MySQL results in a way that is depended on optional fields from other tables and I wonder if that is "easily" achievable.

Here's how the Database looks (sorta):

**MAIN TABLE** called 'Main'

```
    | id |  timestamp |  starttime |
    |  1 | 2010-06-10 | 2010-08-15 |
    |  2 | 2011-01-15 | 2011-03-12 |
    |  3 | 2011-01-27 | 0000-00-00 |
```

**ATTACHED TABLE** called 'Attachments'

```
    | aid |  timestamp | id |
    |   1 | 2012-09-04 |  3 |
    |   2 | 2017-04-01 |  3 |
```

**REVISIONS TABLE** called 'Revisions'

```
    | rid |  timestamp | id |
    |   1 | 2014-10-10 |  1 |
    |   2 | 2018-12-25 |  2 |
```

The Main table is what is basically needed, the attachments and revisions aren't important for the ordered list I want to provide.

Now I want to be able to sort this by "last change date" and this is a problem because there are 4 values that could be sorted by:

1. Main.starttime (this is updated upon certain user actions)
2. Attachments.timestamp (users can add attachments anytime)
3. Revisions.timestamp (a user can edit their Main row, the delta is written into Revisions as a new row)

OR (should none of the above fields exist or are zero)

4. Main.timestamp (which is the default DateTime the row was created, using NOW())

I tried using GREATEST() in my ORDER BY Clause, and that works, but only for Main.timestamp and Main.starttime - not for the other 2 values that I need to take into consideration.

This is my current SQL command:

```
SELECT Main.*, User.lastname, User.surname, User.title
FROM Main, User
WHERE User.uid = Main.uid AND Main.state != 0
ORDER BY $orderby LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

my $orderby variable is handled through PHP so it's sanitized but basically can be something like:

```
$orderby = "Main.timestamp DESC";
```

Or using GREATEST():

```
$orderby = "GREATEST(Main.timestamp, Main.starttime) DESC";
```

The main Problem I face is that not every Row of "Main" has a corresponding row in "Attachments" or "Revisions" but some have multiple.

The example above should be sorted as

```
2 > 3 > 1
```

if the sorting would work.

I hope you guys can help out!

Comment: You can make use of [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) to `ORDER BY` a column in another table.

Comment: "not every Row of "Main" has a corresponding row in "Attachments" or "Revisions" but some have multiple"  => it's LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky, but it works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bUV99RzrxcHkgFyUWUMGEe/0

**Query**

```
SELECT
    MAIN.id,
    MAX(MAIN.updated_at) AS 'updated_at'
FROM (
  SELECT
    M.id,
    GREATEST(
          IFNULL(M.`timestamp`, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
          IFNULL(M.starttime, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
          IFNULL(A.`timestamp`, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
          IFNULL(R.`timestamp`, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
    ) AS 'updated_at'
  FROM
    main M
  LEFT JOIN
    attachment A ON M.id = A.id
  LEFT JOIN
    revision R ON M.id = R.id
) AS MAIN
GROUP BY
    MAIN.id
ORDER BY
    updated_at DESC
```

**Explaination**

I've used a first query to select all your main, and their related attachments and revisions. Then, for each, I computed an `updated_at` field, which takes the greatest between many fields *(note: greatest works bad with null values, hence the `IFNULL(date, '1970-01-01 00:00:00)`, so it assumes at least one date between main timestamp, main starttime, attachment timestamp and revision timestamp is not null).*

At this time the rows are not grouped by main id, so you see 4 rows in the db fiddle.

I used a second query that wrap this last one, and I used `MAX(updated_at) AS 'updated_at'` to grab the maximum of the **grouped** queries (you see the wrapping query called `AS MAIN` is doing a `GROUP BY MAIN.id`, that is why we use `MAX` and not `GREATEST`, this last one takes a list of field and not a grouped field).

At the end, we order by our query and tada!

Hope it helps.